# UITableView one sided Border color?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, colors, border

I'd like to have a tableview border styled like this one,only the left side is colored.

[image: example image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Many ideas! What is your current approach and what did you have problems with??

Comment: I tried using CALayer and SetBorderWidth and SetBorderColor but it sets the entire perimeter border. I just want the left side as shown in the billboard app photo.

Comment: add opaque view above tablewview and you'll get it. Also if there no separators between cell, you can add such view to them.

Comment: I edited your post to embed your image, which keeps people from having to chase your links to help you out.

Comment: simplest way to achieve the above: change the size (in nib) of the table view to not extent to the edges, add small colored rectangle sized view left of the table view with your pretty color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to add a `UIImageView` to your cells that has a small width and the same height with the cell ([example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15)). Another approach would be to use an image as a background for each cell, and add this border in the actual graphic that you will use ([example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)). And if you want to make it in a layer level, a good start is [this example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html). I hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I can think of is to add a little view in the content view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //Just a small view
        UIView *lineView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_POS, Y_POS, LINE_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT)];
        [lineView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:lineView];
        [lineView release];

    }
    return cell;
}
```