# How to set only right border in UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I wanted to set only right border in UITableView?

So far i have tried this below code. But it is setting the border in whole table as it is there in mac, But i wanted to achieve that it should set only right border :-

```
self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of using layer you can add a view to the contentView of the cell the size you want, this add border of 1px:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  ...

  UIView *right = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(319, 0, 1, cell.frame.size.height)];
  right.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  [cell.contentView addSubview:right];
```

Comment: @"llario" Thanks, But if i wanted to draw the same in right. But else i need to do??

Comment: @hussainShabbir with CGRectMake you can put border anywhere you want. in this case x = 319, and width is 1px, so will look to the right

Comment: Thanks, I have changed 319 to 200 and it works fine:)

Answer (score 2):

As I know, you can't add border for one side of UITableView only. Check this answer here, it could help you

[UITableView one sided Border color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544358/uitableview-one-sided-border-color)