# Horizontal Line Separator in Swift 3.x

Tags: uiview, swift3

I need to archive a layout like this:
[image: layout]

I tried using [this guys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43171483) to a similar question, but it didn't worked, I also tried to only set a view's height and a bg color, also didn't work - *even though it displayed the line in the interface builder and preview mdoe*.

I would like to create maybe a custom element, or just to draw a line, that could work with AutoLayout and be displayed at the interface builder.

Comment: Did you take a look at the suggested answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a horizontal `UIStackView` for this purpose. You should set it's alignment to be `Center` and it's distribution to be `Fill`. Then you can add a `UIView, UILabel, UIView` **(in this order)**. Set both `UIView` to have equal width and height and give a height to one of them. In this way your `UIStackView` would be dynamic, in the sense that when the text in your `UILabel` gets bigger the "separators" on both sides would shrink. Don't know if that's what you want to achieve but it could be a possible solution!